# Counting linear maps over finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

I've been looking into linear algebra over finite fields. Given some $F_p=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, it follows that a vector space $V$ with dimension $n$ has $p^n$ elements. I am wondering if there is a way (and a justification along with it) to determine how many linear maps $f:V \rightarrow W$ exist.

By the fact that $cf(x)=f(cx)$, it's apparent that V and W must be over the same field for $f$ to be properly defined. So both V and W are over $F_p$, and have $p^n$ elements. If we strip away the vector space structure for a moment, then there are $(p^n)^{(p^n)}$ morphisms between the underlying sets $\{V\}$ and $\{W\}$. But how many of these, exactly, are linear maps? I'm not too sure how to proceed counting while ensuring linearity.

Comment: Any linear transformation is uniquely determined by its action on a basis. So the answer is $\# W^{\dim V}$.

Answer (score 1):

The linear maps from $V$ to $W$ are in bijection with the choices of the images of the vectors in the basis  of $V$, which are arbitrary. Hence the linear maps are in bijection with the *set* $W^n$. Thus you only have to count the elements of the latter.

Answer (score 1):

There is a canonical isomorphism between the linear maps over $F_p$ and the matrix $M_n(F_p)$. So you can count all of these matrix : for each term in the matrix there is $p$ choices. Finally you have $p^{n^2}$ such maps.