# Find the number of linear function for the given mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Suppose f: $F^n _q → F_q$ then find all the linear functions?
So I understand that $F_q$ is the field with q elements and $F^n_q$ is then the vectors $f_1,f_2,…,f_n$ where each $f_i$ is in the field $F_q$.
But I do not understand how to solve it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A linear function (in the sense of linear algebra) is not a function of the form $x \mapsto mx+b$, it is a function that preserves the vector space structure.

Comment: Adding on what @azif00 said, a linear function is one that satisfies: $f(\alpha x)=\alpha f(x)$ and $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all vectors $x,y\in F_q^n$ and all scalars $\alpha\in F$.

Comment: @azif00 oh okay! I think I mixed up the concepts

Comment: @MichaelMorrow isn't this linear map condition?

Comment: Precisely. Linear function in this context means linear map. They are the same. "Map" is typically another word for "function".

Comment: @MichaelMorrow Oh okay. I will just edit it out then. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Perhaps this may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738192/counting-linear-maps-over-finite-fields

Comment: @MichaelMorrow okay, I will go through it.